# How to use an expression "home in on"?

Tags: expressions

I checked the dictionary and it means **"to aim exactly at an object
or place and move directly to it".**

I would like to use this expression in a sentence.
Could you give me some examples please?

Comment: Have you tried googling "home in on" (with the quotes)? This should give you tons of examples of the phrase being used.

Comment: I know,but I don't get it how to use it by myself.

Comment: But you've only asked for examples. You haven't asked how to use it. Google has millions of examples. If you want to know how to use it, please be more specific about how you want to use it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

"home in" is the actual verb here, meaning something like "move to focus". The most common usage is "home in on X", meaning "move to focus on X". Here are some actual examples:

> Soviet bombers used them to **home in** on targets.
>
> A vaccine designed to "**home in**" on the protein would deliver a message to the immune system to attack the invading cancer
>
> The loopholes have also been used to track people closely, **home in** on their handset and tap into calls and messages.
>
> We hope to **home in** on the crucial underlying biological processes.
>
> We can **home in** on the weeks, days and hours that show us how our lives have shaped in the time before we were born.
>
> The light **homed in** quickly toward the violinist.

Comment: @zondo: Thanks for spotting my inconsistent bold formatting! However, I don't want to change the comma usage because these are actual examples I copied without change from real BBC articles or novels.

Comment: Well, that's okay.  Without my adding commas, it was only four characters changed.  I needed those two extra ones to make it a substantial enough edit.

Answer (score 0):

'Home in on' is a phrasal verb. In its original sense, it's used for a missile, aircraft, or ship aiming for or moving toward its target. It can also be used for something aiming at its target. For examples:

The missile homed in on the enemy's ship.

The shark/tiger homed in on its target.

However, this expression is also used figuratively to mean to focus on or  direct attention to someone or something. For examples:

After a few jokes, he homed in on the main subject.

His speech homed in on his weaknesses.

Doctors are homing in on the cause of her death.